# Why did Dr. Wong switch the sign from Courage to Dedication?

Tags: rick-and-morty

When Beth, Summer, and Morty enter Dr. Wong's office for group therapy, Wong flips the sign outside her office from a man eating a hotdog with the label "Courage" to a happy family with the label "Dedication".

Why did Dr. Wong flip the sign? Is there a joke here I'm missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a recurring joke throughout the episode that most of Dr. Wong's patients (besides the Smith family) are coprophages trying to break their habit. Much as the image of the happy family represents successful therapy for the Smiths, so does the image of a man eating normal food represent successful therapy for a recovering coprophage.

The joke is that Dr. Wong leads a "double-profession" (splitting her time between standard family counselling and getting people to stop eating poop) and is unsuccessfully trying to keep those two worlds separate from each other. We see the joke continued later when Morty finds depictions of coprophagy in a booklet during the counselling session.

The words "courage" and "dedication" appear to be arbitrary filler made to resemble a motivational poster.

Comment: The imagery of a hotdog (which has a relatively similar cylindrical shape) also alludes to this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why but it seems that Dr Wong was hiding the most pertinent image to who ever was waiting for their session. One shows a person eating which was hidden from Goldenfold who was there for eating shit. Then she flips the picture for the Sanchez showing dedication. Something that family is woefully lacking. Can't say I understand how that was a joke.